# Replace multiple substrings within a string

Tags: java, string, replace

I have string such as

```
String url = "www.test.com/blabla/?p1=v1?p2=v2?p3=v3"
```

I would like to replace the "substrings" "v1","v2" and "v3" with other values.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))

Comment: `replace("v1", value1).replace("v2", value2) ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does something like this work for your case?

```
String url = "www.test.com/blabla/?p1=v1?p2=v2?p3=v3";
    
String result = String.format(url.replaceAll("v[0-9]", "%s"), "arg1", "arg2", "arg3");
    
System.out.println(result); //www.test.com/blabla/?p1=arg1?p2=arg2?p3=arg3
```

Edit:
Just a brief explanation of what this does, it replaces all the v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v0 in the original url for %s and then uses this in the format method so you can attribute what you want it to be.